# How prove this inequality with $xyz\ge 1$

Tags: inequality

Let $x,y,z>0$ and such $xyz\ge 1$,show that
$$\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{2}{2+x+3y}\le\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{1}{2+x}$$I tried C-S,Jenson inequality  but without success.

Comment: It might be clearer to expand your sums to include all terms.  Since $z$ does not appear in either summand expression, and $y$ does not appear in the RHS, it's unclear what a "cyclic" summation might mean.

Comment: @wightahtl I have a proof for $xyz=1$. If you wish I can show.

Comment: I see it,   Thanks